# Exceptions not showing up in console unless explicitly caught

Tags: java, logging, exception, spark-java

I'm using SparkJava and it seems that exceptions thrown in routes are not showing up in console unless I explicitly catch them.

For example, given

```
Spark.post("/lookup", this::lookup);
```

and

```
private String lookup(Request req, Response res) {
    // some stuff
    return json.toString();
}
```

If `// some stuff` throws an exception, nothing appears in console. But if I explicitly catch and print the exception, it prints it to console as expected.

```
private String lookup(Request req, Response res) {
    try {
    // some stuff
    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return json.toString();
}
```

This leads me to believe that somewhere further up in the route callstack, all exceptions are caught and hidden.

As you can imagine, this behavior results in some rather frustrating debugging. Is there any way to make it so that all exceptions are always shown in console?

Comment: Try searching for "Java spark swallowing exceptions"

Comment: Do you have a specific link in mind? I tried searching but I couldn't find anything (maybe I am just a bad searcher :( )

Comment: No, I just know it's not uncommon for libraries to swallow exceptions. For example, I'm using the Quil library (for Clojure), and by default it swallows all exceptions. It has an option however to allow exceptions as normal. I've never used SparkJava, but if this is it swallowing exceptions, it may have a setting. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Main class, before any routes, add this:

```
    exception(Exception.class, (exception, request, response) -> {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    });
```

Any exception not otherwise caught by your application code will now be dumped to the console.

(IMO Spark should do this by default...)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had turned to an ugly solution of sticking all my routes in a wrapper class that caught any exceptions; this looks much nicer. Absolutely agree that this should be default..